# Import file python from multiple subfolders

Tags: python, import, subdirectory

How can I import the file file2.py from the file file1.py? Is there a standard method without necessarily using libraries such as sys?

```
project\
  folder1\
    folder2\
      file1.py
  folder3\
    folder4\
      file2.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are best going to use an absolute import so you make sure that your `project` is inside your `sys.path` and then you can just import `project.folder1.folder2.file1` without having to do it relative to `file2`,

if you are working on a package that is not in your python path then I suggest that you make a virtual environment and a setup.py file (look up setuptools for more info) and if you have activated your virtual environment and then run `python setup.py install` (or `python setup.py develop` to use it from the source directory if you are still working on it) then it **will** be in your `sys.path`, - note there are equivalent commands with `pip install .` if you prefer

otherwise if you don't want to do it the "proper" way, you will just have to fiddle with `sys.path` by hand, and yes you will have to `import sys` before you can do that  or set `PYTHONPATH` environment variable before you start python (colon separated list of directories and you will want to include the parent directory of `project`)

Comment: ok thanks mate, I already knew the solution you proposed to me (very practical), mine was more a question to understand if the import could also be done with the 'standard' approach and therefore if I was missing something, apparently not. thanks again for your time